# Get empty Element List for post of my organization

Tags: linkedin-api

I need to retrieve analytics of my companies posts.

I do have the following rights:
r_1st_connections_size
r_ads_reporting
r_basicprofile
r_emailaddress
r_liteprofile
r_organization_social
rw_ads
rw_organization_admin  reporting data"
w_member_social
w_organization_social

for my Bearer token.

But my request:
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:*myOrganisationId*

does return:

```
{
    "paging": {
        "start": 0,
        "count": 10,
        "links": [
            {
                "type": "application/json",
                "rel": "next",
                "href": "/v2/shares?count=10&owners=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%<myOrganisationId>&q=owners&start=0"
            }
        ],
        "total": 568
    },
    "elements": []
}
```

What is strange. Because it genuinely succeeds, and even returns a total > 0 but the elements are ALWAYS for ALL pages empty.

How can that be? Any insights?

I would appreciate also any input on which endpoint provied most easily the most metrics like click-rate, impressions, ... , of the posts?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hi. I'm facing the same issue. Did you figure this out yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve the insigths from a `share` object you need to use the `adAnalyticsV2` endpoint ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting?tabs=http#ad-analytics)).

You can than retrieve the data by querying the endpoint in this way:

```
 https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&pivot=SHARE&timeGranularity=DAILY&shares=List(urn:share:XXXX)
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. But this imposes that I would get the shares Ids somewhere. But as my question points out, I only get empty elements list for the shares. Do you have an idea where I would get the shares ids from in the first place? The /ugcPosts endpoint did work the same meaning only an empty return. Thanks a lot for your support

Answer (score 0):

to get a list of all shares I use this (replace the 00000 with your company ID):

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A00000)&sortBy=LAST_MODIFIED
```

That will actually give you a lot more, than you need but you will have a list of share urns as well as their texts and even authors. I wonder how are you planning to combine the two, cause that's what I am trying to figure out.

Thanks,

Piotrek